# NullPointerException in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android

I am totally new to Android development, so I apologize before hand if what I'm asking is really simple, I've been Googleing around for the past couple of hours with no luck.

In my MainActivity I reference AlarmReceiver.class in an Intent and then into a PendingIntent and finally it is set to an AlarmManager. Which I do to set an alarm, and this works fine, it's when the alarm is triggered the Exception happens.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(ourContext, AlarmReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ourContext, 666, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ourContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

And then in AlarmReceiver.class it extends BroadcastReceiver, and makes an SDK call.
This part of the code in run whenever the Alarm triggers, meaning when the selected time is neigh, run this code.

```
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

    SDK.sendNotification(arg0, new Notification("alarm", "Top Line", "Bottom Line"), new SendNotificationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String s) {
            Log.d("success", s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailed(String s) {
            Log.d("fail", s);
        }
    });
}
```

SendNotification takes 3 variables, a context, a Notification and a NotificationListener.

What I've been able to determine, I am pretty sure that it's the NotificationListener that is the problem and causes the error.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Process: com.example.timer:remote, PID: 27665
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.timer.AlarmReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2452)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.imer.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:21)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2445)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is line 21:

```
SDK.sendNotification(arg0, new Notification("alarm", "Top Line", "Bottom Line"), new SendNotificationListener() {
```

Comment: What is `SDK` and where is it initialized?

Comment: And which is line 21?

Comment: It is initialized in the MainActivity.

Comment: This is line 21: `SDK.sendNotification(arg0, new Notification("alarm", "Top Line", "Bottom Line"), new SendNotificationListener() {`

Comment: `at com.example.imer.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:21)` What is on line 21 of the class?

Comment: @JesperJacobsen paste the relevant code from your `MainActivity`. I suspect it's not initialized properly.

Comment: So ***obviously*** `SDK` is still null.

Comment: SDK.initiate(getActivity(), "DEVCODE", new String[] { Scope }, new AuthListener() {

Comment: It takes Context, String, String[], AuthListener.

It is getting initialized correctly, as the onSuccess code block is being fired for the AuthListener

Comment: What's that supposed to be? If it's meant to be an initialization of the variable `SDK`, it isn't.

Comment: @JesperJacobsen See the answer that was just posted. Your stack trace ends on that line, meaning the only way it can throw a `NPE` is because the symbol `SDK` is not initialized properly. You need `<Type> SDK = ... something...` where `something` is either a function returning an object of `<Type>` or `new <Type>...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the exception is thrown here:

```
  SDK.sendNotification(arg0, 
                       new Notification("alarm", "Top Line", "Bottom Line"), 
                       new SendNotificationListener() {
```

then the *only* possible explanation is that `SDK` is `null`.  Check that it is properly initialized; i.e. a non-null value has been *assigned* to it.  (And check that you don't have multiple declarations ... and that some of them are not initialized.)

---

You posted this as (supposed) counter-evidence.

```
  SDK.initiate(getActivity(), "DEVCODE", new String[] { Scope }, 
               new AuthListener() {
```

1. That doesn't set `SDK` to a non-null value.  It doesn't set (hint: *assign*) anything to `SDK`.

   (But hypothetically, it *would* give an NPE if `SDK` is a variable, it is `null` and `initiate` is an instance method.)
2. That statement may not be executed.
3. Even if *that* `SDK` variable is not `null`, there could be another declaration of `SDK`.

In short, that doesn't prove anything.

Comment: @JesperJacobsen That's a complete waste of time. It *is* null. The exception proves it. That's what you're supposed to be investigating. You should be examining *why* it is null.

Comment: Okay, I am just going through everything, step by step.

I'll accept the answer and hopefully find the cause :)

Comment: Okay, the problem is that when I call the handler, I can not move the SDK over... The SDK from the MainActivity is being set to null, and i am not sure why